# My code for finding prime numbers is not working. what is wrong here?

Tags: c

I am trying to find prime nos up to 1000, but I am only getting 2 and 3.

```
void main()
{
    int i = 1, j, n = 1000;

    while (n != 0)
    {
        j = 2;
        i++;
        if (i % j != 0)
        {
            j++;
        }

        if (i == j)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
            n--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For help with asking a question take the [tour], read [ask] and study  https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: I am curious, if this is your first question, how do you know that asking is hard?

Comment: Walk through your code, either on paper or in the debugger when `i==5`. What would `j` be? Perhaps you need a second loop?

Comment: Please rephrase as a question.

Answer (score 1):

There are problems in your code:

- you should `#include <stdio.h>`
- the prototype for `main` is incorrect, it should return `int`.
- you should initialize `j` outside the loop and run the tests in a slightly different order.
- the code is not designed to *find prime numbers up to 1000*, but to find the first 1000 prime numbers.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// print the first 1000 prime numbers
int main() {
    int i = 2, j = 2, n = 1000;

    while (n != 0) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            if (i == j) {
                printf("%d\n", i);
                n--;
            }
            j = 2;
            i++;
        } else {
            j++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that your algorithm is confusing and inefficient:

- you combine in a single loop what should really be expressed as 2 nested loops.
- you test all divisors up to `i`, whereas you could stop when `j * j > i`, reducing the time complexity from **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** to **O(N<sup>1.5</sup>)**.
- you could also special case `2` and only test odd numbers and divisors, further reducing the number of divisions by another factor.

Here is an alternative:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// print the first 1000 prime numbers
int main() {
    int i, j, n = 1000;

    if (n > 0) {
        printf("%d\n", 2);
        n--;
    }

    i = 3;
    while (n > 0) {
        for (j = 3;; j += 2) {
            if (j * j > i) {
                printf("%d\n", i);
                n--;
                break;
            }
            if (i % j == 0)
                break;
        }
        i += 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has been implemented with a wrong logic. It doesn't look for the first divisor without remainder for each `n`.

To search primes you have to individuate each number that hasn't an integer divisor smaller than the given number, in other words: If the given number divided for all the possible divisors (smaller than it) generates a remainder (the remainder is not 0) it's a prime.

Try this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Computes all primes from 1 to 1000 */
int main(void)
{
    int i,j,n=3; /* n=3 3 is the first odd number to test */

    /* 2 is the only even prime number */
    printf("%4d ",2);

    while(n<1000) {
        /* j=max usefull divisor */
        j=(int)sqrt(n);

        /* scanning divisors (i is the divisor)*/
        for(i=3;i<=j && (n%i);i+=2);

        /* if no divisor found print the number */
        if (i>j) {
            printf("%4d ",n);
        }

        /* Test the next odd number */
        n+=2;
    }
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

This code contains 3 tricks:

- 2 is the only even prime number.
- If a number haven't a divisor within its square root it's a prime number.
- We test only odd numbers (`n=3;` ... `n+=2;`) then the divisors may be only an odd number (`i=3;` ... `i+=2`).

Following your intent and what @Chqrlie said I made this other version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Computes first 1000 primes */
int main(void)
{
    int i,n=3, cnt = 1000; /* n=3 3 is the first odd number to test */
    /* 2 is the only even prime number */
    printf("%4d ",2);
    cnt--; /* 2 was already written */

    while(cnt) {
        /* scanning divisors (i is the divisor)*/
        for(i=3;i*i<n && (n%i);i+=2);

        /* if no divisor found print the number */
        if (i*i>n) {
            printf("%4d ",n);
            cnt--;
        }

        /* Test the next odd number */
        n+=2;
    }

    puts("");

    return 0;
}
```

The code above (as "indicate" @Chqrlie) avoids the square root and computes the first 1000 primes (as you expected from your code).

Comment: This answer does not explain the error in the original code.

Comment: This answer demonstrates that the code needs two loops and the division test in the original code is not correct.

Comment: This answer does not explain the error in the original code. Showing different code, albeit correct, is not an explanation. It does not answer the question asked in the title: What is wrong here?

Comment: if he reads the code here, he may understand the errors of his code! Logical and implementative.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, now there's an explanation ... :)

Comment: @user122984: Using this code you might try to use an other trick. You may store the primes you found and then try the divisions using as divisors the primes you found (and stored) smaller than the square root of the number you're testing.

Comment: @SirJoBlack: the latest code computes and displays one prime too many :)

Comment: Yes ... It's true cause I write 2 out of the loop!!! :p ... @chqrlie ... corrected!!! :)

Comment: @chqrlie, there was an other error ... cnt shall be decreased if the prime is found. Then the old algorithm was printing less than 1000 primes.